# Error: 'file' must be a character string or connection

Tags: r

I'm trying to solve a problem that keeps coming up while trying to load a data table with requirements to read and run in R.

The data reads something like this;

```
>read.table("Nameofdataset.txt")

>newFile <- read.table("Nameofdataset.txt")

>newDat<-read.table("newFile", header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, strip.white=TRUE)
```

but it won't work.

When typing in

```
>newFile
```

the data set comes through but it wont recognise in the 3rd data line:

```
newDat<-read.table("newFile", header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, strip.white=TRUE)
```

The full error code is:

```
Error in read.table(file = newFile, header = FALSE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE,  : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection
```

Can anyone help fix this? I've tried putting the newFile part in as
newFile,

```
>'newFile',

>"newFile",

>file = newFile,

>file = 'newFile',

>file = "newFile",

>File = newFile,

>File = 'newFile',

>File = "newFile",
```

I thought to be a character or string connection it had to be in `''/""`.

And nothing helps. Help??

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer lay in the coding prior to this line of coding; where my initial renaming of the code was written as  "" not '' and was rewritten as a data set and not first into a value, which it needed to be, to then be renamed and converted into data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You have some data (table) in file called "Nameofdataset.txt"? If so, then simply:

```
newDat <- read.table("Nameofdataset.txt", header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, strip.white=TRUE)
```

Comment: you'd think this would help, but somehow it doesnt. It just reiterates the imported data but with "/" instead of spaces (by striping the white (spaces)) but doesn't give clear results using that afterwards

Comment: Perhaps for better context I'm trying to eventually graph a spatial network of coordinates and a matrix of data (of which the coordinates are the hypothetical 'nameofdataset'.txt.)